# Scanning all physical memory

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to scan all my memory for a specific variable via nasm. 
My current code looks a bit like this:

```
%include "io64.inc"
%define VAR 1234
section .text
global main
main:
    mov     rax, 0x0
nxt:
    mov     rbx, [rax]
    cmp     rbx, VAR
    je      end
    inc     rax
    jmp     nxt
end:
    PRINT_HEX 8,rax
    ret
```

My problem is this is generating segmentation faults sooner or later (Depending on the starting address it may run a few cycles and then fail). When googling about ways to do it I did not find any answers on the topic. I suspect that the cs and ss registers may have to do something with it but how exactly I do not know.
I know that cheat engine is capable of doing it so there has to be a way to do it.

**tl;dr**
Trying to read memory, getting segmentation faults; How do I avoid them? What other alternatives are there? (Preferably without requiring admin rights)

Additional info:

- OS: Win 10 Pro 64bit
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210M@2.60GHz 2 Cores, 4 Threads
- RAM: 8gb DDR3

Thank you for any answers

Comment: You can't scan all of physical memory from a user mode program under Windows. What you're actually scanning is virtual memory and you're only seeing memory allocated for the process specifically. Any region of the virtual address space that isn't allocated won't be mapped and trying to access it will cause segmentation fault.

Comment: @RossRidge thanks ^^. any way to bypass that? Or anything you can link me to read about the topic?

Comment: You can open a process and read its memory, it looks like that's the intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first: you are running on an OS that that uses virtual memory and your process only works with and sees *virtual* addresses, and has an address space that's (barring some shared read-only pages) separate and distinct from the address space of other processes.

This means that barring special APIs that an OS may expose, there's simply no way you can scan all the *physical* memory from a *userspace* program.

You should see why this is a good thing. If the OS allowed random userspace prorgams to scan the entirety of physical memory, that would be a huge breach of security.

Your program is crashing because you're accessing virtual addresses which aren't yet mapped to anything.